# GStreamer on M1 Mac

Tags: gstreamer

I've been battling to get the GStreamer tutorials running on my M1 Mac (via XCode) and its down to the last error.

```
ld: warning: dylib (/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/GStreamer) was built for newer macOS version (10.11) than being linked (10.6)
ld: file not found: @rpath/lib/libgsttag-1.0.0.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`libgsttag-1.0.0.dylib` is on my machine but I guess XCode is unable to find it. Has anyone got the tutorials running out of the box on an M1?

Comment: When in doubt I use [Brew](https://brew.sh/) - it has a [gstreamer](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gstreamer#default) for "Apple Silicon".  I've not tried it myself.

Comment: I've read that this can mess with package installs. I'll swing over to my other laptop and see if Brew comes through.

Comment: Having the exact same issue as you -- were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to build from source? If you are, it sounds like the architecture target is confused. x86 would be for an older Intel mac, and this is an M1 (arm64). If you are trying to compile but aren't doing that for any reason other than wanting gstreamer in any way you can get it, I would recommend using the downloads from the gstreamer site instead. There are universal binaries with both x86 and arm64 dylibs. That might help, but without understanding what you need, I'm not sure.